# Java - Reading in a CSV file into a constructor

Tags: java, javafx

**Java (Constructor issue)**

Trying to figure out how to read in a CSV file into a constructor. Theme is harry potter and I'm reading in 4 files (**Gryffindor**, **Hufflepuff**, **Ravenclaw**, **Slytherin**). Reading this into my **House.java**, but **School.java** and **Student.java** have constructors/getters and setters as well. Supplied below. For instance a within a **School** exists a **House** and within that exists a **Student**. In the 4 CSV files provided, each file is a name of a **"House"** in which you would read in the file as **"Students"** (first name, last name, year).

These 3 java files are within application.model to support an application in JavaFX using the MVC format. It's specifically tailored in this fashion for the sake of grading.

**House.java**

```
public class House {

 private String name;
 private String color;
 private String professor;
 public ArrayList<Student> Students;

 public House(String name, String color, String professor, ArrayList stdList) {
     this.name = name;
     this.color = color;
     this.professor = professor;
     this.Students = stdList;
 }

public ArrayList<Student> sortStudents(ArrayList<Student> allStudents) {
    if (allStudents != null) {
        Collections.sort(allStudents, new SortTool());
    }
    return allStudents;
}

 public void dataLoader() {
    String fileName = "Gryffindor.csv";
    String content = null;
        /*
        * Shows working path System.out.println(newFile(".").getAbsoluteFile());
        */
    try {
        Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        // Delimits by commas and (enter or \n)
        inputStream.useDelimiter("[,\n]");
        // Iteration rather than iterable
        while (inputStream.hasNext()) {
            content = inputStream.nextLine();
        }
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**School.java**

```
public class School {
 private String name;
 private int enrollment;
 private House houses[];

 /*
 * School Constructor
 *
 * @param pass in name to set name
 */
 public School(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    houses = new House[4];
    enrollment = 0;
   }
}
```

**Student.java**

```
public class Student {
 private String firstName;
 private String lastName;
 private int year;

 public Student(String firstName, String lastName, int year) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.year = year;
   }
}
```

**SortTool.java**
public class SortTool implements Comparator {

```
@Override
public int compare(Student a, Student b) {
int c = a.getYear() - b.getYear();

if (c == 0)
    c = a.getLastName().compareTo(b.getLastName());
if (c == 0)
    c = a.getFirstName().compareTo(b.getFirstName());

return c;
}
```

}

Trying to be discrete about the entire program since I wrote it and don't want it to be tracked as plagerism.
House.java - how do I read into this CSV file into a constructor. Comma delmited and needs to be read in and not manually entered.

*Example of Gryffindor.csv*

Colin Creevy,1, Hermione Granger,2, Harry Potter 2,

Comment: Your question isn't very clear.  What do you mean by reading "into a constructor"?  Are you saying that you think the constructor should contain the code that reads the CSV file?  Some people would consider this poor design.

Comment: I’m with @DawoodibnKareem here; doing the reading and whatnot in the constructor might not be the best idea. The constructor is primarily used to create an instance of an object.

Comment: Sorry,

For instance a within a School exists a House and within that exists a Student. In the 4 CSV files provided, each file is a name of a "House" in which you would read in the file as "Students" (first name, last name, year).

Comment: @notyou These 3 java files are within application.model to support an application in JavaFX using the MVC format. It's specifically tailored in this fashion for the sake of grading.

Comment: This question has elements that aren't related to your use of a constructor.  Try breaking down the problem into smaller components and see if you can more clearly explain what you're having trouble with.  For example, what do you do with `content` in `dataLoader()`?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can read the file the constructor of the House class. Just add a private method that will populate the Students arrayList. 
You have to open the file giving the path of where each houses files are located and append it with "/"+this.name+".csv", and then for each line of the file you read, you parse it and add a new Student in the arraylist. 
Example of the method :

```
private void populateHouseFromFile(){
    String line;
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(PATH_TO_HOUSES+"/"+this.name+".csv"));
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] split = line.split(",",3); //Retrieve each part of the student information , assuming each field is separated with a "," and each line is new entry.
        this.Students.add(new Student(split[0],split[1],Integer.decoded(split[2])));
    }
}
```

You should check that int the constructor of student that the argument passed are not stupid (negative year, etc if bad constructed .csv).

Comment: On the line:
this.Students.add(new Student(line[0],line[1],Integer.decoded(line[2])));

It's stating that for line[0] for example is "- The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to String"

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to attribute the split value to a string and use it, I correct my answer wait a second. It should work now.